# AWS Lambda cannot connect to endpoint in different VPC unless existing CNAME myservice.vpc is deleted and re-created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I was wondering if someone can suggest a solution to this:

If I have an AWS lambda in one VPC.

The lambda makes an HTTP Get request to an endpoint in a different VPC.

There is a Route 53 CNAME to the different VPC (myservice.vpc) which already exists.

The lambda cannot connect to the endpoint and times out.

If I delete and re-create the myservice.vpc Route 53 CNAME, the lambda successfully connects to the endpoint.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Thanks

Miles.

Comment: Random networking issues with AWS Lambda functions are sometimes caused by configuring the Lambda function to connect to multiple subnets within a VPC, but only some of those subnets have Internet connectivity. If you want the Lambda function to be able to access the Internet, either _DO NOT_ connect the Lambda function to a VPC or ensure that the Lambda function is only connected to **private subnets** and deploy a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet of the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John's suggestion that this could be a networking issue. AWS Lambda functions might face issues when connected to multiple subnets within a VPC, especially if only some of those subnets have internet connectivity. However, there is another potential issue that could be causing the problem you're experiencing.

It might be that the DNS resolution for the CNAME record is being cached somewhere in your system or network. AWS Route 53 follows the TTL (Time to Live) setting for each DNS record, which specifies how long a resolver is supposed to cache the DNS query before the query expires and a new one needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you the suggestions.  The Lambda is making a single HTTP Get request to another VPC.  The myservice.vpc CNAME entry is in a Route53 private hosted zone.  I'm not sure if this adds "anything" to my question.  Thanks Miles.